# Web.config redirect all paths to index.php - not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, web-config, windows-server

I predominantly work with Apache and .htaccess, but I am currently working on a site that is hosted on a Windows server. The Web.config is causing me a lot of problems.

I am trying to redirect all the URL requests to the index.php so that the PHP script can then parse the URL and serve up the correct page.

The .htaccess (which works fine on Apache) is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [NC,L]
```

The Web.config rewrite (which doesn't want to work):

```
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="rule 1G" stopProcessing="false">
                <match url="^(.*)$"  ignoreCase="true" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/-"  />
            </rule>
            <rule name="rule 2G" stopProcessing="false">
                <match url="^(.*)$"  ignoreCase="true" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="//index.php"  />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Here is the site on my Apache testing server: http://villasilvana.hotmintmedia.com
And here on the live Windows server: http://www.villasilvana.net (UPDATE - I've had to revert the live site back to the original, as it is still in use)

I have trawled through countless pages on ISS and Web.config and tried many variations on the rewrite code, none of which have worked. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 14):

I know it's a bit late in the day, but in case anyone else is looking

```
<!--web.config url rewrite-->
<configuration> 
  <system.webServer>
      <rewrite>
          <rules>
              <rule name="Redirect To Index" stopProcessing="true">
                  <match url=".*" />
                  <conditions>
                      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                  </conditions>
                  <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php" />
              </rule>
          </rules>
      </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: This does not work if you have `%2B` in the URL. This broke my registration URLs, since they contain secret code in the url.

Comment: could you please check my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67955362/how-set-uri-rewrite-to-read-specific-url-or-file?noredirect=1#comment120111414_67955362)