# How set uri rewrite to read specific url or file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, routes, url-rewriting

I am a bit confused of how using uri rewrite. I have a project which includes c# web api 2 and angular, I want to get data from web api. so I use this in my `web.config` :

```
<system.webServer>

<rewrite>

      <rules>
        <rule name="AngularJS Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="./index.html" />
    </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

what I expect is opening `index.html` by typing `http://localhost/`. But I get **HTTP 404** *The resource cannot be found.* however when I type `http://localhost/index.html`, my program start to work without any problem. I was wondering how can I achieve this by typing `http://localhost/`
[image: url rewrite which added to iis]

Comment: I think the result which you are trying to achieve can be simply achieved via an angular routing module

Comment: @Arjunsinhjadeja could you explain more, how it could be?

Comment: Can't you just specify the path in app.module.ts under `imports` with whichever component you want to load. Like this. `RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' }
    ])`

Comment: @Arjunsinhjadeja what you say is routing on angular and for opening components, my problem is utilizing angular and webApi 2 both in production mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well after researching I found a way to get **.html** type of file, so I changed my `web.config` file like this:

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2">
      <buildProviders >
        <add extension=".htm" type="System.Web.Compilation.PageBuildProvider"  />
        <add extension=".html" type="System.Web.Compilation.PageBuildProvider"/>
      </buildProviders>   
 </compilation>
```

then my application worked fine.