# Why does my HTTP GET call to a subroute in react app gives a 404 NOT Found instead of HTML?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, web-config, react-router-dom

When I try to do a **GET call** to a subroute of my **react** application I get a **404**.
When I do this to my homepage it returns correctly the HTML.
**When just accessing the subroutes via the browser my webpage gets correctly rendered.**
I'm Using **React version 16.9.0**.
I'm hosting the web application in Azure App service.

The reason for this question is to use an external program that can check for deadlinks in a website. At the moment I get 404's for every call to a subroute.

GET calls in Postman:

> [www.test.be](http://www.test.be) => works
>
> [www.test.be/custom-route](http://www.test.be/custom-route) => gives a 404

This is my React Router Wrapper component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from 'home/containers/home-container.js';
import NotFoundPage from './error-pages/not-found-page';
import Questions from 'questions/containers/question-container.js';

const Body = () => {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
      <Route path="/questions" component={Questions} />
      <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
    </Switch>
  );
};

export default Body;
```

This is my web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters="&lt;,&gt;,*,&amp;,:,\\,?" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="HTTPSs">
          <match url="(.*)"/>
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="Off"/>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="true" pattern="^localhost" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}"/>
        </rule>
        <rule name="ReactRoutes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_METHOD}" pattern="^GET$" />
            <add input="{HTTP_ACCEPT}" pattern="^text/html" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true"/>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: It would help if you include the type of server you use to serve the react app

Comment: I dont see /custom-route defined. Makes sense to me to go to the 404 fallback if you try to access this path.

Answer (score 4):

You don't provide complete details but If I understand correctly, it can help you to solve your problem, if you have this problem on the server and when you open the homepage it works correctly and when open a subroute it goes to 404 page, add this to your **.htaccess** file

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because how reactjs applications gets deployed on your production WebServer.

Reactjs applications are served deployed on with single index.html. Entire entire react project is served from index.html (This is how 'www.test.be' works). React-router programmatically updates the browser URL based on which page you navigate.

When your visit  'www.test.be/custom-url', the request is first caught and processed by the webserver. The webserver is expecting HTML file named 'custom-url.html' doesn't find it. So webserver throws a '404' i.e. 'Page not found' error. The request is not forwarded to your ReactApp - so your ReactApp never gets a chance to process the request.

The solution depends on the type of hosting service you are using. Basically, you want to redirect all URLs to React App (index.html) so that React Application will get a chance to process 404.

Update your question with the hosting service you are using (such as netlify, heroku, aws etc) and I can update this answer with a solution suitable for that hosting service.

For instance, if the webhost is netlify, you can create a file called _redirect in public/ directory with the following content

```
/*  /index.html  200
```

That will redirect all traffic (*) to index.html

Comment: I'm using an app service from Azure to host my website. Is that enough information?

Comment: Try this https://www.rahulpnath.com/blog/create-react-app-devops/

Answer (score 1):

It happens because you don't have `SSR` (*Server-Side Rendering*). probably you're using CRA to create your ReactJs web application, so it works with CSR and the sub-routes couldn't be understood by server.

I don't mean bring SSR to your project, because you should be serious about using SSR for some special reasons. by the way, there is a very simple solutions for any kind of servers, you should redirect all requests to the `index.html` then `react-router` can understand the sub-route in the client:

### Redirect all to `index.html`:

- [PM2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/) server:

  ```
  pm2 start [path-to-build-folder/app.js] --spa
  ```
- [Serve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve):

  ```
  serve -s [path-to-build-folder/app.js]
  ```
- [IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26506775/6877799):

  ```
  <!--web.config url rewrite-->
  <configuration> 
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Redirect To Index" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
  </configuration>
  ```

I don't know how you deployed your ReactJs web application, because some time DevOps specialist use running ReactJs app by using `serve`, `pm2` or `node` under a special port for example: **8008** then by using IIS proxy try to connect the web application to local process, so by calling the port 80 user will be able to see the website. Also, you can directly serve the application by serving `index.html` in the IIS, and totally your solution is *redirecting all requests to `index.html`*.

Hope this answer helps you.

Answer (score 0):

try this web.config :)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="React Routes" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>

</configuration>
```